# Real-time Multiplayer Game - region broadcasting

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, sockets

I'm coding a **real-time multiplayer game** (with Nodejs, socket.io) and I would like to ask your help to optimize one point.

I implemented an authoritative server with an updates loop **60 times/s** and a broadcast loop **20 times/s**, client-side prediction and interpolation. 
Then, in the broadcast loop, I tried **region broadcasting** that lead to a performance issue.

To be minimalist, the Server has arrays of :

- Player entities (id + positions)
- Food entities (id + positions)

Let's **spawn 1000 foods** in a big map (just like agar.io), in an array *server.foods* of the Server. Player only needs to know the state of the foods in his viewport (let's say **200 visible foods**). So, the Server only sends **one packet** with the 200 visible foods (id + positions) to the Player. Then, to keep the Server knowing, we push the 200 visible foods in an array in the Player object (*player.foods*)

But the Player can move, so others packets have to be sent :

- **initFoods** that is an array of foods (id+positions) to init (only if NEW foods are visible to the Player : *distFoodPlayer < 500*)
- **removeFoods** that is an array of foods (id+positions) to remove (only if NEW foods are not visible to the Player : *distFoodPlayer > 600*)

To know these informations, I do something like this :

```
for (var i = server.foods.length; i--;) {
    //Edit: added the next line
    if (distPlayerFood < 900) {
        var food = server.foods.entities[i];
        var inPlayerFoods = false;
        for (var j = player.foods.length; j--;) {
            if (food.id === player.foods[j]) {
                inPlayerFoods = true;
                if (distPlayerFood > 600) {
                    removeFoods.push(food.id);
                    player.foods.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        if (distPlayerFood < 500) {
            if (!inPlayerFoods) {
                player.foods.push(food.id);
                initFoods.push([food.id, food.state]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The performance is ok for 1000 foods and 1 player (updates loop of the server keeping ~58FPS). But for 5000 foods and 1 player (or 1000 foods and 5 player), the performance is really bad because of this double loop (server going to ~25-40FPS max) BUT the bandwidth is minimized.
The tests of performance have been done on my computer (localhost). Maybe with bigger servers, I will not have these problems ?

Do you think I did a good approach ? Do you have a better idea ?

Thank you very much.

**Edit** : I changed the code to only check the foods not too far. Server is going to ~35-50FPS max though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of your algorithm is O(n!), that's why it gets slow a big amount of food. Your approach seems fine unless your goal is to make the player move in a big world. One way to optimize your implementation that worked for me would be to divide your world into tiles, each tile containing references to the foods inside it. Then you can quickly get a list of *possibly in range* foods, which saves you from checking the distance between the player and the foods that are too far away.

Comment: Divide the array. That's genius, thanks !

So we have the viewport of the player (i.e. radius of 900) and an additional scope to send him a new food just before it appears in his viewport (depending on the latency of the server, let's say +100). The size of one tile would be 100x100, right ? The server would loop on ~π*10² tiles (list of _possibly in range_ foods).
Better, the server can loop on the only tiles 900 to 1000px away from the Player (~2*π*10 tiles) for adding/deleting foods

Comment: You can have various tile sizes, as long as you never miss any one that's in the radius. So 100x100 is fine as long as you don't forget a tile that touches the viewport. If you want simplicity you can also use 450x450 tiles, this way you just have to check the current player's tile and the 8 nearby ones (assuming your viewport has a radius of 900).